# A Simple google map - wordpress custom plugin - Map No show

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, wordpress-plugin-creation

[2 files map plugin -github](https://github.com/digital6s/Googlemap-wp/tree/master)

I'm above to give up please help... noob here.

Created custom style google map with generated code from googles style map wizard site thing
Followed the instructions and various tutorials, jsfiddles, and all sorts and am just so confused.

I put the code into GitHub so you can see what I'm working with.  On my site the scripts.js is inside the folder, (first time on GitHub/new to JS and PHP and can't figure how to move the js file into a folder on GitHub lol)

Have confirmed that All the scripts are loading in the head - YAY
The  is loading on my page
The CSS is loading  #put-map {height:300px; width:300px;}
But the actual map isn't
API is working from local host (tested static html page with apu and custom style map)
No error in browser just doesn't display the actual map.
Is it the event listener - addDomListener - perhaps something there isnt right - I have no idea.

I am trying to create simple ultra lite base map plugin, that I can just replace style or location code for when I want to use maps, I am relying too much on Elementor sites getting really clunky, so trying to expand my knowledge to be less dependent on visual page builders... REALLY appreciate any offers to help with this,

This is my first js project, I'm guessing I've just missed something small, or am COMPLETELY OFF… Anyway I've only included the JS here, as I'm 95% sure the php is fine, but the link to the whole thing is above

Cheers Ness

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// JS for Google Map with Custom Style obtained https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
// Function to create the map
function initMap() {

// create variable themap and define the element id for use in html ie to be used like: <div id="put-map"></div>
var themap = document.getElementById( 'put-map' );

// create variable mapOptions and define options and information for the map to display     
var mapOptions = {
// Generated long and lat from https://www.latlong.net/
  center: {
    lat: -37.345,
    lng: 144.146
      },
    zoom: 12,
    
    // Disable all the controls https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls
    // in this case i don't want the use to have any options to change the map position or zon in etc.
    
    disableDefaultUI: true,
 
       //******************************************************************************
       //
       //  Custom map visual styling
       //  Styles applied from wizard https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
       //   - Cut and paste JSON Code from below //**** to above next //****
       //******************************************************************************
       
    styles: [
      {
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "color": "#f5f5f5"
          }
        ]
      },
```

more style code is here but cut it to keep it shorter i cut and past from JSON off google between the stars

```
    ] 
    //****************************************************************************** 
//end of Style part 
  }; //end of Map Options
// create a new map using the information and options defined in the variables themap and mapOptions
var map = new google.maps.Map( themap, mapOptions );     
  }  //ends function initMap 
// Create a DOM event to tell the site to load the createmap function when it finds <div id="mymap"></div> on the web page 
google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initMap );
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Correction "The is loading on my page " - it removed a bit it should say...  the div id="map" etc is loading on my page.

Answer (score 0):

OHHHH SOOO  EXCITED I was way overcomplicating it... and I think I had most of the right bits but in the wrong places, I was pretty close.  I also think that I might have been updating the script.js file outside my activated plugin  so the changes were not actually reflecting on the page - Rookie error eh, either way I've cleaned it all up and its working.

Eventually I found this awesome video hidden amongst all the how to use Google Maps with HTML embed/iframes or how to get an API :( but this video actually shows you step by step [Google Maps JavaScript API Tutorial by Traversay Media](https://github.com/digital6s/Googlemap-wp) enough to get the right idea...  I only needed the first few minutes as the video goes on to tutorial how to add markers and other fancy features, that i didnt need.

I have a GitHub repository (new to Git too) and in the code I have over commented to explain what (I think) is happening in the PHP/JS, what resources I used to generate bits of code from googles map wizards, where certain variables and names need to be the same and also where you need to make changes.  There are no instructions on getting your JavaScript Map API there are plenty of these around.

The plug in consists of 3 very short files, so I'm sure there are different ways of presenting some parts of the code, or some ways of doing it more efficiently, please remember I'm still learning this is my first plugin, first finished bit of real PHP, and very first use of JavaScript

Really happy that I resolved from resources I found myself, was really exciting. I hope this helps others.

[GitHub - Googlemap-wp by Vanessa](https://github.com/digital6s/Googlemap-wp)